# Organizing data

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm having a little problem. I am developing a PHPCodeigniter web application which has a complex data and I'm confused about how to organize this.

I have 4 sites:

- jobsite1.com
- jobsite2.com
- jobsite3.com
- mainsite.com (dashboard for all the jobsites)

My Question:

- Where to save jobs data? Localsite or in Mainsite
- If we're going to use the mainsite as the container for the jobs data. Does it affect the load of the jobsites?

I'm newbie with this kind of set-up. Any suggestion and recommendation will be welcomed. I need also to anticipate where to save the applicants' data of these jobsites. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they all do the same, then put them in mainsite and identify which jobsite the data refers to, so if you want to add more sites, you dont have to re-write the main site to cope with more data sources

Comment: Thanks @Waygood its a nice idea and I'm thinking also the advantages and disadvantages on all the jobsites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer largely depends on a few factors :

- how much cross processing do you need, ie does jobsite1 need the data from jobsite2? does mainsite need raw data from jobsite1 etc? Do services work good enough or is raw SQL access a must? (Think scalability if this grows)
- the volume of data we're talking about. If these have the potential to grow, it will be easier to manage them as independent sites ( eg move jobsite1 and jobsite2 to their own server, or separate clouds )
- finally, if something goes wrong and one of the sites is hacked, if each has its own database, you're likely only going to restore one site, not all of them.

Personally, since these are different sites, I'd keep them separate, and use services ( eg REST ) to have them talk with each other.

Comment: Some data jobsite1 will be need to jobsite2 and to following jobsites (eg post job in jobsite1 and duplicate in jobsite2). Mainsite also contains all the jobs in all the jobsites. We are using different server for seo purpose and SSO for these sites.

Comment: how much data do you expect ? thousants? tens, hundreds of thousants? if you're only looking to show a few ( eg first 100 ) cross site, keep them separate. If you need them all to be accessible, or too many, use services or even simple iframes to show what you need.